# PHP : How to show complete hyperlink in sms

Tags: php, sms, twilio-php

I am sending sms to mobile using twilio sms service in PHP http://s.test.com?v=ccc but in sms it only show http://s.test.com as a hypelink missing `?v=ccc` part . how can I make it show this whole http://s.test.com?v=ccc as a hyperlink in sms ?

This is the code I am using to send sms :

```
function sendText($number, $id, $product_domain)
{
  $short_url = 'http://s.'. $product_domain .'.com?v='.$this->toBase($id);

  $client = new Services_Twilio(TWILIOSID, TWILIOTOKEN);
  $client->account->messages->sendMessage("123-4567-9870", $number,
"Your Scope is complete ".$short_url."  Customer Service  877.697.2673 . To disable this service reply with \"stop\"");
 }
```

This `$short_url` will be generated as `http://s.test.com?v=ccc`

Comment: That's pretty strange since your code itself seems to be fine. If you can't find the right answer you might consider rewriting the url to `http://s.test.com/ccc` as the problem may be caused by the question mark. The second advantage of doing so is that you safe two digits.

Comment: thanks for the reply i will consider doing so if i don't find any other solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `http://s.test.com?v=ccc` to `http://s.test.com/?v=ccc` fixed the issue for me.